# Error Message When Running MyBatis at the first time

Tags: java, jboss, mybatis

I have a strange problem when running my application in JBOSS at the first time:
The error message is:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value for project.services.dao.workerDAO.getAllWorkers
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:535)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:433)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Mapper File: project.services.dao.sql.workerDAO.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >

<mapper namespace="project.services.dao.workerDAO">

    <select id="getAllWorkers" parameterType="java.lang.String"
        resultType="Worker">

         Select wrk.Id As workerId, wrk.Nm As workerName
         From Worker wrk

    </select>

</mapper>
```

However, for the second time, there is no Error Message.

Comment: The full stacktrace and your config may help.

Comment: see here once https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=291

Comment: please post the code.Otherwise it is difficult

Comment: post you full error stack and database access code.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same trouble, and finally I find the reason is that there are repetitional SQL id in mapping xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in MyBatis. The java class **`workerDAO`** can't take the same name as a mapper **`workerDAO.xml`**. So, try to change the mapper to **`workerMapper.xml`** then test. Please read this [article](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IBATIS-625) for more information. I hope it's helpful.